# Typecasting in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

In cpp

```
EBD_HEADER* pHeader;

pHeader = reinterpret_cast <EBD_HEADER*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(const_cast <char*> (GetHeader())));
```

In Objective C

```
EBD_HEADER* pHeader;

pHeader = (EBD_HEADER*)((void*)((char*)([self GetHeader])));
```

Why is these so many casts needed. Is it wrong to convert it into (EBD_HEADER*)[self GetHeader];

Comment: Obj C can accept `C` syntax, I think it is the same under C.

Comment: And maybe consider the deeper question of why `[self GetHeader]` is returning the wrong type :-)

Comment: so (EBD_HEADER*)[self GetHeader] will also return the same value as the cpp syntax with so many cast isnt it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need that many casts in C/Objective-C, you should just use one cast for simplicity:

```
pHeader = (EBD_HEADER*)[self GetHeader];
```

With C++-style casts, you need two casts because one casts away the `const`-ness and the other reinterprets the pointer to one type to a pointer to another type; the intermediate cast to `void*` is redundant and should be removed.

However, in this case, you should try to refactor the code so that you don't need any casts at all.  Why does `[self GetHeader]` return a `const char*` instead of an `EBD_HEADER*`?  Is the object returned actually constant?  If so, you should declare `pHeader` as `const EBD_HEADER*`, and you should not cast away the `const`-ness; if not, then `[self GetHeader]` should not return a `const` type.